# How focus a textbox after using extjs Ext.MessageBox.alert

Tags: extjs

I want to validate my extjs form. When the text field is empty, there should display an alert box and after that our cursor have to focus on the text box. I tried with the coding below. Alert is working fine. but cursor is not focusing. Can you please help me anybody to focus?

```
if(Ext.get('first').dom.value=='')
{
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Enter your First Name!');
    document.getElementById("first").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.MessageBox) states that MessageBox is asynchronous:

> Note that the MessageBox is
>   asynchronous. Unlike a regular
>   JavaScript alert (which will halt
>   browser execution), showing a
>   MessageBox will not cause the code to
>   stop. For this reason, if you have
>   code that should only run after some
>   user feedback from the MessageBox, you
>   must use a callback function (see the
>   function parameter for show for more
>   details).

So, your focus() is carried out immediately after the call to Ext.MessageBox.alert, not when the user dismisses it: When the user clicks to dismiss the alert, the focus will change again.

You could try using a regular javascript alert() instead, which is synchronous.

Comment: i am not getting your answer. but i tried with reguler js code and
Ext.get('first').dom.focus() also. But i am not getting correct.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (Ext.get("first").dom.value == "") {
    Ext.MessageBox.alert("Status", "Enter your First Name!", function() {
        Ext.get("first").focus();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(Ext.get('first').dom.value=='')
{
     Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Enter your First Name!', function(btn, text){
          if (btn == 'ok'){
               Ext.getCmp('first').focus(true,10);
          }
     });
}
```